# View log of maven commands run by Eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I often found myself in a situation where I would like to see exactly which Maven commands Eclipse is running behind the scenes. In this case I am running a webapp with WTP, but this question is more general (though I would gladly accept answers for just that scenario).

Is there any way either with a pom configuration or an Eclipse configuration to view a log of all commands (and potentially any output) that any Eclipse plugin (or at least m2eclipse-wtp) have run?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Maven Console will show you the Maven output from m2e and m2eclipse - access it from the very right hand side dropdown of the normal Console view.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that was there. However, I see no Maven console logging when I run a web app, so perhaps Maven is not involved at that point. I will prob fix my question to be more general and accept your answer.

Comment: @smp7d Even i cant see Maven logging even when the project build is happening. Is there any additional configuration required ?